# How can I return multiple error types using `Result`?

Tags: sockets, rust, openssl, network-programming

I'm using OpenSSL to open an encrypted connection with a webserver. I want to set this up so that one function that opens the TLS connection will be able to handle multiple errors by returning those errors to the main function. The problem I'm currently facing is that `Result<T, E>` currently only allows me to return one type to the main function to be handled.

Here is a snippet of the code I'm trying to write:

```
use openssl::{self, error::ErrorStack, ssl::{HandshakeError, SslConnector, SslMethod, SslStream}};
use std::net::TcpStream;

pub fn ssl_connect(server: &str) -> Result<SslStream<TcpStream>, HandshakeError<TcpStream>> {
    let ssl_context = SslConnector::builder(SslMethod::tls_client()).unwrap().build();
    let stream = TcpStream::connect(format!("{}:31988", server))?;
    let ssl_connector = ssl_context.connect(server, stream)?;
    Ok(ssl_connector)
}
```

This works great in the situation where the TLS handshake fails, but if the TCP handshake fails for some reason (like no route to host) the main program panics and shuts down.